# Convert to Relational Algebra

Tags: sql

I want to convert this in relational algebra but I'm confused on how to do it. The SQL code is here:

```
SELECT title, pid, year, rank  
FROM directors 
NATURAL JOIN productions 
NATURAL JOIN ratings 
NATURAL JOIN persons 
WHERE (attr IS NULL 
  AND votes > 50000 
  AND directors.pid = 'Bigelow, Kathryn' 
  AND gender = 'F');
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results

Comment: Avoid natural joins like the plague. They are obscure and error prone.